# Algebraic function $u\in C^\infty(\Bbb R^n)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

Suppose $u\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is an [algebraic function](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Algebraic_function) that has no singularities. Can it be said that $u$ is a polynomial?

If instead $u\in C^\infty(\Bbb R^n)$ and is an algebraic function. Is it also a polynomial?

Comment: @Alizter: So its obvious (or perhaps trivial) to you that in dimension one $u$ must be a polynomial?

Comment: Your wording is unclear. I will fix my edit. Tell me if it is better now. Somebody cast close votes on this for being unclear. I am trying to help it to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks.Its totally clear right now.That somebody voted to close it before the fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

too good to be true. Here is a middle school counterexample:
Let $u(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ then $(x^2+1)u(x)-1=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}.$